# Can I define multiple metrics_set in pipeline.config for TF2 Obejct Detection API

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, object-detection, object-detection-api

I have been trying to know if I can define multiple metrics_set for one model. I read the source code, I have read lots of writing, even learned proto2 syntax to see if it's possible to agument the code as I want. But couldn't get any results. (Also .config files doesn't look like written in proto2).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

> The TensorFlow Object Detection API currently supports three evaluation protocols, that can be configured in EvalConfig by setting metrics_set to the corresponding value.

1. coco_detection_metrics
2. pascal_voc_detection_metrics
3. oid_V2_detection_metrics

That means, right of the bat `tensorflow 2.X` supports 3 evaluation metrics and their slight variations. Tensorflow mentions them in the project, but you have to download them and compile the protobufs yourself and have it under your python project. [This](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/evaluation_protocols.md) mentions a list of tensorflow supported and already available evaluation metrics.

For installing `coco_detection_metrics` and having them in your project do the following :

```
git clone https://github.com/cocodataset/cocoapi.git
cd coco/PythonAPI && make
```

> if I can define multiple metrics_set for one model?

Changing the `pipeline.config` won't help you do that. Evaluation is actually a separate process that you have to run. In my opinion you can definitely run more than one evaluation on your training directory pointing to a separate `pipeline.config` file whilst the training is going on.

Have your config files as so as an example.

```
#file coco.config
eval_config: {
  metrics_set: "coco_detection_metrics"
  use_moving_averages: false
  batch_size: 1
  num_visualizations: 10
  max_num_boxes_to_visualize: 5
  visualize_groundtruth_boxes: true
  eval_interval_secs: 30
}
... other stuff
--
#file pascal.config
eval_config: {
  metrics_set: "pascal_voc_detection_metrics"
  use_moving_averages: false
  batch_size: 1
  num_visualizations: 10
  max_num_boxes_to_visualize: 5
  visualize_groundtruth_boxes: true
  eval_interval_secs: 30
}
.... other stuff
```

Then run both the evaluations simultaneously. Have a separate tensorboard running in two different ports to view each.

```
!python object_detection/model_main_tf2.py \
--pipeline_config_path={pipeline_file} \
--model_dir='path/to/training/dir' \
--alsologtostderr \
--checkpoint_dir='path/to/training/checkpoint'
```